# Scan & Get all IP addresses of all other devices on network with android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, sony, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

I want to create tv remote control and product owner is required BaseUrl is IPAddress of TV Device. So I need scan all other devices on network to get IP address of device.

Comment: Why would a TV remote be using IP?  Either infrared or bluetooth are more normal choices.  But in general, on a well maintained network you can't do this.  The wifi router generally used in a residence will act as a firewall preventing devices from seeing each other.

Comment: @GabeSechan Because I want to build remote control app, so I need connect Android Phone to Smart TV via Wifi

Comment: the tv lines I plan to connect are: Sony, Samsung,

Comment: I pretty much garuntee that they use bluetooth and not wifi.  For them to use wifi, they'd either need to run a server on the TV and you'd need to poke a hole in your router's NAT, or there would need to be an external Sony/Samsung server in the mix, which would be a horrible design as the TV would not work if you lost internet.

Comment: https://pro-bravia.sony.net/develop/integrate/ip-control/index.html This is document to build app tv remote control for Sony Bravia brand. It includes docs about RESTAPI, we need BaseUrl is TV's IP Address and services of SonyBravia on docs

Comment: Well that means I'll never be buying a SOny TV again.  Horrible idea.  But it shows you in the docs how to get the IP from the TV itself. There is no way to get a list of all devices on a WAN.  You'll also almost certainly have to reconfigure your wifi router to make it work.